# Rebind a UDP socket with a new address?

Tags: c, networking, udp, datagram

With a UDP socket, if the FQDN has its IP changed, is there an simple way to rebind the socket with the new address?

Or is it as simple as just calling bind() again with the socket and providing the new address since UDP is connectionless? ie I don't have to close the socket to ensure it's still not in use.

Comment: No. You have to close the socket and create a new one.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Thanks!